# How Can I Convert a String to a Ufunc?

Tags: python, numpy, function, type-conversion, numpy-ufunc

I am trying to write a simple function that converts an input written in LaTeX to a ufunc that can be read by numpy. So far, I'm testing the function by converting `\sin(x)` to `np.sin(x)` (ignoring the conversion from {} to (). I'm not that familiar with ufuncs so I keep running into an error when trying to convert the `\sin(x)` string to the `np.sin(x)` ufunc for any given x.

```
import numpy as np

latexEq = input()

def latexMap(latexEq):
    if "\sin" in latexEq:
        sinLatex = latexEq.replace("\sin", "np.sin")
    else:
        pass
    return sinLatex

npOutput = np.ufunc(latexMap(latexEq))
print(f"f(x)={numpyOutput}")
```

Similar to how an integer may be converted into a string `str(2)`, I tried enclosed both `sinLatex`, `latexEq`, `"np.sin"`, and `npOutput` but the error I always receive is

```
TypeError: cannot create 'numpy.ufunc' instances
```

Any explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: What about just returning `np.sin`?

Comment: I can't do that because I'm planning to use this type of function to convert more complex LaTeX to NumPy ufuncs.

Comment: `np.sin` is a Python function.  `np.ufunc` does not convert a string to the function.

Comment: I do not think this approach of converting LaTeX to NumPy you are going for is going to work well. There is a lot of work done already into parsing equations like [`latex2sympy2`](https://github.com/OrangeX4/latex2sympy) which should give you some ideas.

Comment: You can map string to functions with a `dict`, e.g. `{'sin':np.sin, 'cos': np.cos}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you just have `npOutput = "np.sin"` (without the `(x)`) you can do

```
# function_name = getattr(module, function_name_string)
npOutput = getattr(np, npOutput.lstrip("np."))
```

which gives you the function `np.sin`. The parentheses have to be gone because otherwise it would be a function *call*, not a function.